# Is the linking of prebuilt_static_libraries order sensitive in Android.mk?

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, ros

The below file is basically auto-generated from a script I got from ROS website, except for it that I modified some opencv related packages so that they can fit into my ROS project. Use Ctrl-F + "opencv" and you can find those names in variable "stlibs".

The error happens when I was linking opencv-3.3.1 to an open-source ROS project using NDK. I got many "undefined reference" errors from the opencv static library but those referred functions should be packed in other opencv .a files, right?

So I am wondering... does the order of those prebuilt_static_libraries in Android.mk matter? If so, could any one help me that?

Related Android.mk in */path/to/the/file/ros-android-ndk*:

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

    # These must go in some sort of order like include flags, otherwise they are dropped
    # Oh no, need to automate this with catkin somehow....
    stlibs := roscpp boost_signals boost_filesystem rosconsole \
rosconsole_print rosconsole_backend_interface boost_regex xmlrpcpp \
roscpp_serialization rostime boost_date_time cpp_common boost_system \
boost_thread console_bridge move_base rotate_recovery global_planner \
navfn layers boost_iostreams qhullstatic flann_cpp_s flann_cpp_s-gd \
nodeletlib bondcpp uuid rosbag rosbag_storage roslz4 lz4 topic_tools \
voxel_grid tf tf2_ros actionlib tf2 move_slow_and_clear \
dwa_local_planner clear_costmap_recovery carrot_planner \
base_local_planner trajectory_planner_ros urdfdom_sensor \
urdfdom_model_state urdfdom_model urdfdom_world rosconsole_bridge \
pointcloud_filters laser_scan_filters mean params increment median \
transfer_function compressed_image_transport cv_bridge image_transport \
compressed_depth_image_transport amcl_sensors amcl_map amcl_pf \
stereo_image_proc image_proc image_geometry ***opencv_imgproc \
opencv_core opencv_flann opencv_highgui opencv_features2d opencv_ml \
opencv_imgcodecs opencv_calib3d opencv_video opencv_objdetect \
opencv_photo opencv_videostab opencv_superres opencv_stitching \
opencv_dnn opencv_shape opencv_videoio*** cpufeatures IlmImf libjasper \
libjpeg libpng libprotobuf libtiff libwebp tbb tegra_hal polled_camera \
camera_info_manager collada_parser geometric_shapes octomap octomath \
shape_tools random_numbers camera_calibration_parsers costmap_2d \
laser_geometry message_filters resource_retriever \
dynamic_reconfigure_config_init_mutex tinyxml class_loader \
PocoFoundation roslib rospack boost_program_options pcl_ros_filters \
pcl_ros_io pcl_ros_tf pcl_common pcl_octree pcl_kdtree pcl_search \
pcl_sample_consensus pcl_filters pcl_io pcl_features pcl_registration \
pcl_keypoints pcl_ml pcl_segmentation pcl_stereo pcl_tracking \
pcl_recognition pcl_surface pluginlib pluginlib_tutorials \
image_transport_plugins nodelet_math yaml-cpp 

    #shlibs :=

    define include_shlib
    $(eval include $$(CLEAR_VARS))
    $(eval LOCAL_MODULE := $(1))
    $(eval LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $$(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/lib$(1).so)
    $(eval include $$(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY))
    endef
    define include_stlib
    $(eval include $$(CLEAR_VARS))
    $(eval LOCAL_MODULE := $(1))
    $(eval LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $$(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/lib$(1).a)
    $(eval include $$(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY))
    endef

    #$(foreach shlib,$(shlibs),$(eval $(call include_shlib,$(shlib))))
    $(foreach stlib,$(stlibs),$(eval $(call include_stlib,$(stlib))))

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE    := roscpp_android_ndk
    LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
    LOCAL_EXPORT_CPPFLAGS := -fexceptions -frtti
    #LOCAL_SRC_FILES := dummy.cpp
    LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := $(foreach l,$(shlibs),-l$(l)) -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/lib
    #LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -lstdc++ #-L$(LOCAL_PATH)/lib
    #LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := $(shlibs)
    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := $(stlibs) gnustl_static

    include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

The error Message is as follows,

```
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(calibration.cpp.o):calibration.cpp:function icvGetRectangles(CvMat const*, CvMat const*, CvMat const*, CvMat const*, CvSize, cv::Rect_<float>&, cv::Rect_<float>&): error: undefined reference to 'cvUndistortPoints'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(calibration.cpp.o):calibration.cpp:function cvRodrigues2: error: undefined reference to 'cv::checkRange(cv::_InputArray const&, bool, cv::Point_<int>*, double, double)'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(calibration.cpp.o):calibration.cpp:function cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2: error: undefined reference to 'cvUndistortPoints'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(calibration.cpp.o):calibration.cpp:function cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2: error: undefined reference to 'cvCheckArr'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(calibration.cpp.o):calibration.cpp:function cvStereoRectify: error: undefined reference to 'cvUndistortPoints'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(calibration.cpp.o):calibration.cpp:function cv::rectify3Collinear(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::Size_<int>, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, double, cv::Size_<int>, cv::Rect_<int>*, cv::Rect_<int>*, int): error: undefined reference to 'cv::undistortPoints(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(calibration.cpp.o):calibration.cpp:function cv::rectify3Collinear(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::Size_<int>, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, double, cv::Size_<int>, cv::Rect_<int>*, cv::Rect_<int>*, int): error: undefined reference to 'cv::undistortPoints(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(ptsetreg.cpp.o):ptsetreg.cpp:function cv::PointSetRegistrator::~PointSetRegistrator(): error: undefined reference to 'cv::Algorithm::~Algorithm()'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(ptsetreg.cpp.o):ptsetreg.cpp:function cv::PointSetRegistrator::~PointSetRegistrator(): error: undefined reference to 'cv::Algorithm::~Algorithm()'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(ptsetreg.cpp.o):ptsetreg.cpp:function cv::LMeDSPointSetRegistrator::~LMeDSPointSetRegistrator(): error: undefined reference to 'cv::Algorithm::~Algorithm()'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(ptsetreg.cpp.o):ptsetreg.cpp:function cv::LMeDSPointSetRegistrator::~LMeDSPointSetRegistrator(): error: undefined reference to 'cv::Algorithm::~Algorithm()'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(ptsetreg.cpp.o):ptsetreg.cpp:function cv::createRANSACPointSetRegistrator(cv::Ptr<cv::PointSetRegistrator::Callback> const&, int, double, double, int): error: undefined reference to 'cv::Algorithm::Algorithm()'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(ptsetreg.cpp.o):ptsetreg.cpp:function cv::createLMeDSPointSetRegistrator(cv::Ptr<cv::PointSetRegistrator::Callback> const&, int, double, int): error: undefined reference to 'cv::Algorithm::Algorithm()'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(ptsetreg.cpp.o):ptsetreg.cpp:typeinfo for cv::PointSetRegistrator: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for cv::Algorithm'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(ptsetreg.cpp.o):ptsetreg.cpp:vtable for cv::PointSetRegistrator: error: undefined reference to 'cv::Algorithm::save(cv::String const&) const'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(ptsetreg.cpp.o):ptsetreg.cpp:vtable for cv::PointSetRegistrator: error: undefined reference to 'cv::Algorithm::getDefaultName() const'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(ptsetreg.cpp.o):ptsetreg.cpp:vtable for cv::RANSACPointSetRegistrator: error: undefined reference to 'cv::Algorithm::save(cv::String const&) const'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(ptsetreg.cpp.o):ptsetreg.cpp:vtable for cv::RANSACPointSetRegistrator: error: undefined reference to 'cv::Algorithm::getDefaultName() const'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(ptsetreg.cpp.o):ptsetreg.cpp:vtable for cv::LMeDSPointSetRegistrator: error: undefined reference to 'cv::Algorithm::save(cv::String const&) const'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(ptsetreg.cpp.o):ptsetreg.cpp:vtable for cv::LMeDSPointSetRegistrator: error: undefined reference to 'cv::Algorithm::getDefaultName() const'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(solvepnp.cpp.o):solvepnp.cpp:function cv::solvePnP(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, bool, int): error: undefined reference to 'cv::undistortPoints(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(solvepnp.cpp.o):solvepnp.cpp:function cv::solvePnP(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, bool, int): error: undefined reference to 'cv::undistortPoints(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(levmarq.cpp.o):levmarq.cpp:function cv::createLMSolver(cv::Ptr<cv::LMSolver::Callback> const&, int): error: undefined reference to 'cv::Algorithm::Algorithm()'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(levmarq.cpp.o):levmarq.cpp:typeinfo for cv::LMSolver: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for cv::Algorithm'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(levmarq.cpp.o):levmarq.cpp:vtable for cv::LMSolver: error: undefined reference to 'cv::Algorithm::save(cv::String const&) const'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(levmarq.cpp.o):levmarq.cpp:vtable for cv::LMSolver: error: undefined reference to 'cv::Algorithm::getDefaultName() const'
    /home/csx/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/roscpp_android_ndk/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a(triangulate.cpp.o):triangulate.cpp:function cvCorrectMatches: error: undefined reference to 'cvSolvePoly'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, linker success depends on the order of static libraries. See https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/545 and some workarounds there, e.g.

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -Wl,--start-group -L $(TARGET_OUT) $(foreach l,$(stlibs),-l $(l)) -Wl,--end-group
```

Space between `-l` and `$(l)` is intended, otherwise NDK will complain.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV 3.3.x had some trouble with supporting Android NDK R15+ releases, you can see that in their official [changelog](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog) , try to update your OCV to the latest version (3.4.1) and see if the problem persists.